# Web Logic10.3.4 Server Startup Arguments in admin console not working

Tags: weblogic-10.x

We need to set up the command line argument for weblogic ,which can be given in startupWebLogoc.cmd file . But we would like to configure it in admin console. Admin console has the option to configure Node manager server start up arguments .

If i am not using node manager ,is there any option to set up server startup arguments in Admin Console.

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at nodemanager.properties and ensure to set StartScriptEnabled to false.